# How to make C# methods work like javascript functions?

Tags: c#, object-oriented, javascript, functional-programming, methodology

I'll keep it simple, I want to make C#'s methods work like javascript's functions. Mainly so I can convert this -

```
function makeVariable(terp) {
    var me = {value: 0};
    return function () { terp.stack.push(me); };
}
```

into C#. Is there ANY way, no matter how complex or time consuming, to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is entirely possible although you have to be consistent with your types. The technical term for this is [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29).

```
public Action MakeAction(State s)
{
    var me = new Item();
    return () => s.Stack.Push(me);
}
```